# TabBar changes style after app-Introduction

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller, tabbar, uitabbaritem

I've the following problem:
The design of my tabBar is set in AppDelegate.m:

```
       self.tabBarController = (UITabBarController*)self.window.rootViewController;
            UITabBar     *tabBar = self.tabBarController.tabBar;
            UITabBarItem *tabBarItem1 = [tabBar.items objectAtIndex:0];
        tabBarItem1.title = @"Start";
   // ...
         [tabBarItem1 setFinishedSelectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"start_selected.png"] withFinishedUnselectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"start.png"]];
  // ...
```

But after a first introduction pageViewController, which is opened in my tabBarController through an alert, the user goes back to the tabBarController. But then all my tabBar-settings from the appDelegate are gone...

...method to go back to the tabBarController:

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MyStoryboard" bundle:nil];
        TabBarViewController *vc = (TabBarViewController *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"TBVC"]; //this is the tabBarController in the InterfaceBuilder
        [self vc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

**UPDATE**

...I open the introduction in appDelegate:

```
 self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
            self.viewController = [[IntroViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"IntroViewController" bundle:nil];
            self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
            [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Maybe someone can help me and I hope my first question is not so bad.

Comment: Make sure that you're not doing anything in any of the loaded UIViewControllers from viewDidLoad that could cause this.

Comment: @Stavash The only thing I do is setting some badges

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you're going back, you're instantiating a new tabBar controller. This means that it won't be the same one you've configured with your custom settings.

Instead, dismiss the alert or whatever it is you show properly.

Comment: And how can I avoid this...I'm very new to iOS-programming

Comment: Add the code you're using for displaying the alert in the 'introduction' phase

Comment: In TabBarViewController's viewDidLoad - define the custom settings you want the tab bar to have. Don't instantiate the tabBar until you're done displaying the intro.